# How to dynamically add ng-options for select in custom directive of angularJS?

Tags: angularjs-directive

Not sure, it is the correct approach or not.

1. Inside html file, I just use below code:

   ```
   select id="family" nt-field="true"/
   ```
2. ntModule.js

   ```
   .directive('ntField', ['$document', function($scope,$document) {
       return {
           link: function(scope, element, attr) {
               var type = element[0].type;
               switch(type){
               case 'select-one':
                   var id = element[0].id;
                   switch(id){
                   case 'family':
                       scope.selectOptions = "opt.desc for opt in serviceRenewal.system.controller.families.options track by opt.name";
                       attr.$set('ng-options',scope.selectOptions);
                       attr.$set('ng-model','familyModel');
                       attr.$observe('ng-options',function(value){
                           console.log(value);
                       });
                       break;
                   }

                   break;

               }

           }
       }
   ```

I am newbie in angularJS.